# Interfere some UI properties base on the changes during the animation

Tags: ios, animation

My question is that, I want to build an ease out animation, for example like, I want to move an UIView from a point to b point in 1 second in ease-out mode. On the other hand, I want to set some specific background color on the UIView base on the immediate position during the animation.

Is it possible to use Core Animation? Or is there any other ways except using timer?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you changing your color continuously from one value to another or discretely?

Comment: Continuously actually. I need to watch the position in every frame, and possibly set the some properties like background color based on it.

Comment: how do you calc the color according to the position, could you please show the code?

Comment: That was a complex scenario, I will make it simple and paste the code here later.

Comment: I attached the source code in this thread. It is simpler to understand my question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28359705/how-to-continuously-monitor-a-uiviews-location-in-animation

Answer (score 1):

If you are changing the background color **continuously**, I believe you can use CABasicAnimation with the same curve, since backgroundColor is an animatable property.

code like this:

```
CABasicAnimation *changeColor =
   [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"backgroundColor"];
changeColor.fromValue = (id)[UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;
changeColor.toValue   = (id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
changeColor.duration  = myMovingAnimationTime;
changeColor.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];

[self.myLayer addAnimation:changeColor
                   forKey:@"Change color"];
```

If you are only changing the color at specific position, which means changing color **discretely**, I suggest that you set a timer that fires every 1/60 seconds, in the timer callback, you do this:

```
CALayer *presentationLayer = [[myView layer] presentationLayer];
//set color according to presentationLayer.frame
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. I think the second way does the trick. I will give it a try. Let's wait for a day and see if there is any other solutions.